# How can I remove the "padding" of a QTabWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtabwidget

I have a `QTabWidget` with a `QTableWidget` inside, as the example below:

[image]

But it has a "padding" (at least I think it is a padding) in the `QTabWidget` (marked as red in the figure).

**How can I remove that or expand the QTableWidget to fill the QTabWidget area?**

I am using Qt 5.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the "pane" margin of the `QTabWidget`.

I solved the problem by using this on the stylesheet:

```
QTabWidget::pane {
    border: 0 solid white;
    margin: -13px -9px -13px -9px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this :

```
tabwidget.setStyleSheet("QTabWidget::pane { 
 margin: 0px,1px,1px,1px;
 border: 2px solid #020202;
 border-radius: 7px;
 padding: 1px;
 background-color: #E6E6E3;
}");
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score -1):

When you put `QTableWidget` to `QTabWidget` tab, you can right click on it (`QTabWidget`) and select `Lay out -> Lay out vertically` (for example, or horizontally), this will add an verticalLayout element and place your `QTableWidget` into it, filling the whole tab. Then, select newly created verticalLayout, scroll down to `Layout` section, and from here you can control `layoutLeftMargin`, `layoutTopMargin`, `layoutRightMargin` and `layoutBottomMargin` properties:

[image: Qt Creator, UI Editor, Layout Margins]

Setting all of them to 0, will give you desired result (no stylesheets involved):

[image]

Comment: Hi @Dmitriy, thanks for the answer. Actually, I added a Vertical Layout to my QTabWidget (using the upper layout menu from the Qt Design) but the Layout options does not appear on my Property Editor.

Comment: I am looking for something similar, but in your example, you can still clearly see a 1 pixel margin between the inner frame and the tab widget itself.
So, it does not remove it completely?